# Discord bot token resetting itself

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am getting follow message from discord and they keep resetting my bot token. Any assistance what could be wrong.

It appears your bot, TEST, has connected to Discord more than 1000 times within a short time period. Since this kind of behavior is usually a result of a bug we have gone ahead and reset your bot's token.

Comment: Maybe provide the code used so someone can debug the issue.

Comment: **here is the code** [link] (https://pastebin.com/nr0wSpSm)

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to accomplish ? It seems like you are instantiating many discord clients and trying to login all of them. You need to create only one Discord client, and login only once. Also, would you please paste your code directly in your question body, rather than on pastebin ?

Comment: @Gruntzy, Code is too big , it wont fit in question body.

Comment: Can you explain what your bot is supposed to do with your `start` method and your `client.on("message", ... )` ? Your code is creating a new client everytime it handles a message, which is unnecessary.

Comment: Its a discord relay bot, copying messages from one of my servers to another. So messages is picked from channel 123 from server A and lands in channel 999 in Server B. @Gruntzy

Answer (score 1):

In your on message event

```
client.on('message', async msg => {
    msg.content = filter(msg.content)

    let channelid1 = 'xxxx' //
    let channelid2 = 'xx' //

    if (msg.channel.id == channelid1 && msg.author.id != client.user.id) {
        let attach = msg.attachments.array()
        let test = getUrls(msg.content);
        let arr = Array.from(test);
        let emojiname = ''

        if (msg.content.startsWith("<:uparrow:")) {
            emojiname = 'uparrow'
        } else if (msg.content.startsWith("<:downarrow:")) {
            emojiname = 'downarrow'
        }

        let name = msg.guild.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name == emojiname);
        let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setDescription(msg.content)
            .setColor('#A9A9A9')

        if (name) {
            start("Bot token xxxxx", 'Landing Discord channel ID xxx', embed, name)
        } else {
            start("Bot token xxxxx", 'Landing Discord channel ID xxx', embed)
        }

        if(arr.length > 0){
        for(let i in arr){
         start("Bot token xxxxx", 'Landing Discord channel ID xxx', arr[i])
         }
        }

        if (attach.length > 0) {
            start("Bot token xxxxx", 'Landing Discord channel ID xxx', attach[0].url)
        }
client.login('Client token xxxx') //
}
```

You need to remove calling the login function

```
client.login('Client token xxxx')
```

as you don't want your bot re-logging in every time the event  is fired.

Comment: I tried that. Commented out ```//client.login(token)``` Bot comes up online but does not relay messages . Reverted back and messages start coming. May be i need something else

Comment: My bad, you have two client.login, remove the second one that looks like this
client.login('Client token xxxx')

Comment: 1st one is ```client.login(token)``` and 2nd one is where actual token id is mentioned ```client.login('11111111')``` .  If i remove the 2nd one then bot wont login.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, every time the event is fired, it'll log into your bot again. Discord recognizes this and then resets your token. I would recommend removing

```js
client.login('Client token xxxx') //
```

and putting it out of any events. You should also remove

```js
client.login(token)
```